# jqGrid data retrieve

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I'm trying to retrieve a data into my data table ( jqGrid )

I'm able to get a JSON format with all columns and correct data.

however, I'm not able to load it into to table itself..

this is my aspx file code :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: "ajaxWebService.asmx/LoadData",
            mtype: "GET",
            loadonce: true,
            datatype: "json",
            colModel: [

                  {
                      label: "Edit your item",
                      name: "actions",
                      width: 20,
                      formatter: "actions",
                      formatoptions: {
                          keys: true,
                          editOptions: {},
                          addOptions: {},
                          delOptions: {}
                      }
                  },

            { label: 'Date', name: "date", width: 20, editable: true },
            { label: 'Qty', name: "qty", width: 50, editable: true },
            { label: 'Product Name', name: "ProductName", width: 50, editable: true }

            ],
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 780,
            height: 250,
            rowNum: 10,

            pager: "#jqGridPager"
        });
    });
```

and this is my code behind function :

```
public string LoadData()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Products", cn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    da.Fill(ds);

    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

    Dictionary<string, object> row;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }

        rows.Add(row);
    }

    string jsonString = js.Serialize(rows);

    return "{ \"rows\":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows) + "}";
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

You posted the code fragment of your server code. I suppose that you makes too much JSON serialization. I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start, and then use Network tab) to trace HTTP traffic between the client and the server.

The correct formatted data in the body of the server response could be

```
[
    {"date", "2015-03-09", "qty": 2, "ProductName": "foo"},
    {"date", "2015-03-10", "qty": 5, "ProductName": "bar"}
]
```

or

```
"rows": [
    {"date", "2015-03-09", "qty": 2, "ProductName": "foo"},
    {"date", "2015-03-10", "qty": 5, "ProductName": "bar"}
]
```

If you see some additional **backslashes** before every `"` (I mean `\"`) then you made **unneeded** JSON serialization and you should remove the call of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. The returned value of `LoadData` function should be changed from `string` to `object`.

The next typical problem could be wrapping the results of the server response in `{"d": "..."}`. In the case you will need to use `jsonReader` parameter which informs jqGrid to get the important part of the response from `d` property of the response:

```
jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "d" }
```

or

```
jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "d.rows" }
```

depend on the exact format of the server response.